# Adding a feature count to a label in the legend in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, legend, count

In ArcMap, I want the labels in the legend to include the count of that type of feature. For example, if I have a building feature class with a Type field where 900 buildings have a value meaning residential and 40 have the value for industrial, I want the labels to say "Residential - 900" and "Industrial - 40". What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What have you tried?  Did you enable the "Show Feature Count" in Legend properties? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/working-with-legends.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2040FE26EC974FB99067448A6C8C7380

Answer (score 1):

It was as easy as enabling "Show Feature Count" in the legend's properties.